# How to only show dialog after successfully validated text field

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

So I have form with 1 fields that need to be `required`

```
<h:form id="form">
    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
        <h:inputText id="default" requiredMessage="This field is required." 
                     value="#{displayName.name}" required="true" />
        <p:message for="default"/>
    </h:panelGrid>
    <p:commandButton value="Test" update="form" onclick="displayDlg.show();"/>
</h:form>
<p:dialog header="Dialog" widgetVar="displayDlg" id="dialog">
    <h:outputText value="The name you just input is: #{displayName.name}"/>
</p:dialog>
```

So when I click button `Test`, and **not** having anything inside the text-box, then an error message pop out.

I want that if the validation process success, then I want to display a dialog box that display name that you just type in. But if validation fail, then dont diplay the dialog. And I have a hard time making this happen. I try to put the `dialog` inside or outside the dialog, but no work. Please give me some advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make use of the `visible` attribute of `<p:dialog>` and ajax-update the whole dialog.

```
<h:form id="form">
    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
        <h:inputText id="default" requiredMessage="This field is required." 
                     value="#{displayName.name}" required="true" />
        <p:message for="default"/>
    </h:panelGrid>
    <p:commandButton value="Test" update="form :dialog" />
</h:form>
<p:dialog id="dialog" header="Dialog" visible="#{not empty displayName.name}">
    <h:outputText value="The name you just input is: #{displayName.name}"/>
</p:dialog>
```

Additional benefit of having `:dialog` in the `update` is that it will update the entered name as well everytime you change it.

Comment: Thank you BalusC. This work great. Do you mind if I ask why there is a colon `:` next to `dialog`, like this `:dialog`.

Comment: Because it's not inside the same naming container parent as the button. The `:` prefix makes the client ID absolute to the view root instead of relative to the current closest naming container parent (which is the `<h:form>`).